# Помогите решить задачу. В первом ответе должно быть 29278 , а у меня 18178

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

> В файле содержится последовательность из 10 000 целых положительных чисел. Каждое число не превышает 10 000. Определите и запишите в ответе сначала количество пар элементов последовательности, у которых сумма элементов кратна 60 и хотя бы один элемент из пары делится на 40,  В данной задаче под парой подразумевается два различных элемента последовательности. Порядок элементов в паре не важен.
> *https://inf-ege.sdamgia.ru/problem?id=37368*

```
  int main()
{
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
SetConsoleCP(1251);

ifstream file;
string namefile = "17.txt";
file.open(namefile);
if (!file.is_open())
{
    cout << "Файл не открылся! " << endl;
    file.close();
}
else
{
    cout << "Файл успешно открылся!" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    int s;          
    unsigned int counter = 0;

    vector<int> myArray;
    while (!file.eof())
    {          
        file >> s;          
        myArray.push_back(s);
    }
    file.close();
    myArray.pop_back();
   
    cout << "Размер вектора: "<< myArray.size() << endl;
    cout << "Последний элемент:  " << myArray[myArray.size()-1] << endl;
    for (short unsigned int i = 0; i < myArray.size(); i++)
    {
        for (short unsigned int j=1 ; j < myArray.size(); j++)
        {
            if ((((myArray[i] + myArray[j]) % 60)) == 0)                  
            {
                if (((myArray[i] % 40) || (myArray[j] % 40)) == 0)
                {
                    counter++;
                }                 
            }
            
        }
    }       
    cout << endl;
      cout << "Первый ответ: " << counter << endl;         
        //18178
     return 0;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Первый цикл можно заканчивать чуть пораньше

Второй цикл нужно начинать чуть попозже, чтобы одни и те же пары не считать дважды

В условии нужно каждое выражение сравнивать на равенство с нулём

```
 for (short unsigned int i = 0; i < myArray.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        for (short unsigned int j=i+1 ; j < myArray.size(); j++)
        {
            if ((((myArray[i] + myArray[j]) % 60)) == 0)                  
            {
                if (((myArray[i] % 40)==0) || ((myArray[j] % 40) == 0))
                {
                    counter++;
                }                 
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое , я долго не мог разобраться

Comment: @Андрей Ответ можно пометить как решение галочкой слева